# Access to the variable datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've written the code, click on each row of the datagridview row data into a variable would

Now I want to access this variable through the Form_Load but I do not know how?

Please guide

```
 private void dtg_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
      var  custommer = dtg.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as Customer;
    }
```

Comment: Set public property your variable and then access it.

Comment: I guess not possible. How can you click a `DataGridView` before the form load ? You'll always get null even if you use instance variable.

Comment: Form is loaded 
Then click on the datagrid